# ADB0000 fast dev directory creation failed

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

when I run xamarin android app on mobile phone i have a error 
adb0000 fastdevdirectorycreationfailed and 
adb0000 deployment failed

what i have to do to fix this problems?

Comment: Did you create a new emulator? Then run your project, if you can get the same error?

Comment: Try to turn off the Fast Deployment in VS like thie screenshot https://imgur.com/a/kuj9Av5,  then run your app in your mobile device.

Comment: ok thanks for your answers

Comment: Turn off the  Fast Deployment in VS, does it solve your issue?

Comment: yes it solves thanks

Comment: I post my comment to answer, please mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try to turn off the Fast Deployment in VS like thie screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/65kyY.jpg, then run your app in your mobile device